# XSL: Pulling our first 5 matching values only, with sorting

Tags: xml, xslt

I have 5 stations that need to be filled.  This XML outputs waiting guests, with most recent at the bottom.  I need to go up the XML, filling each of the 5 stations.  You basically break them into groups by transactionID, and read the file from bottom up, looking at top position of each grouping.  If we haven't already filled that VirtualDisplayId slot, they get inserted.

So, you'll see we grouped transaction 7773324, and the top-most entry was Justin K02084, so he gets Id 101.  Then the next grouping (7773323), Andy 2084's top entry is also Id 101, which Justin just filled, so here's where my XSLT falls apart.  I'm bringing Andyk2084 into 101, and I need to skip him, and the next entry should be Andy2083, because his transaction's top entry is 201, which I have not yet filled, so he gets 201.  That logic should repeat until all 5 slots are filled.

My other issue is that I can't seem to figure out how to only fill 5 slots.  My XSL just keeps going:)  This is easily the trickiest XSL I've ever written, so finally caved in and am asking if anyone can give me some pointers.

My Output So far:

```
<table>
   <tr><td>JUSTIN K2084</td><td>101</td></tr>
   <tr><td>ANDY K2084</td><td>101</td></tr>
   <tr><td>ANDY K2083</td><td>201</td></tr>
   <tr><td>ANDY K2082</td><td>301</td></tr>
   <tr><td>ANDY K2081</td><td>401</td></tr>
   <tr><td>ANDY K2080</td><td>501</td></tr>
   <tr><td>ANDY K2079</td><td>101</td></tr>...[LOOPS THROUGH ENTIRE FILE]
</table>
```

Desired Output:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>JUSTIN K2084</td><td>101</td></tr>
    <tr><td>ANDY K2083</td><td>201</td></tr>
    <tr><td>ANDY K2082</td><td>301</td></tr>
    <tr><td>ANDY K2081</td><td>401</td></tr>
    <tr><td>ANDY K2080</td><td>501</td></tr>
</table>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
            <xsl:for-each select="SpeedOfService">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="ServiceTiming" group-by="TransactionNumber">
                    <xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="VirtualDisplayId">                    
                        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                            <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/TableName"/></td><td><xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/VirtualDisplayId"/></td></tr>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<SpeedOfService>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773317</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>200</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2078</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773318</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>100</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2079</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773319</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>501</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2080</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773319</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>401</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2080</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773319</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>301</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2080</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773319</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>201</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2080</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773319</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>101</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2080</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773320</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>401</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2081</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773320</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>501</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2081</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773320</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>301</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2081</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773320</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>201</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2081</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773320</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>101</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2081</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773321</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>301</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2082</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773321</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>501</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2082</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773321</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>401</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2082</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773321</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>201</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2082</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773321</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>101</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2082</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773322</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>201</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2083</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773322</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>501</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2083</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773322</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>401</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2083</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773322</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>301</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2083</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773322</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>101</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2083</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773323</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>101</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2084</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773323</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>501</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2084</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773323</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>401</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2084</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773323</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>301</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2084</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773323</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>201</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>ANDY K2084</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
    <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773324</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>101</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>JUSTIN K2084</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773324</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>501</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>JUSTIN K2084</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773324</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>401</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>JUSTIN K2084</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773324</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>301</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>JUSTIN K2084</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
  <ServiceTiming>
    <TransactionNumber>7773324</TransactionNumber>
    <VirtualDisplayId>201</VirtualDisplayId>
    <TableName>JUSTIN K2084</TableName>
  </ServiceTiming>
</SpeedOfService>
```

Comment: You could wrap another template around it and select only the ones where position() < 6

Comment: Where is the *ANDY K2084* in the Transaction *7773324* in sample post? In fact, there are no Andys in that transaction. Be sure your example is [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, my samples were good, but I made a typo as I was explaining.  Andy K0284 is in 7773323.  The original XML was over a meg, so I trimmed it, but I think I have a working example.

Comment: The sequence of  `101`, `201` etc. of your desired output looks like you want unique values for `VirtualDisplayId` so I would start grouping on that first. I am not sure however which `TableName` you want to associate with such a unique `VirtualDisplayId`, can you explain in plain words which value that is?

Comment: Eiríkr's answer worked perfectly (sorry, I was on vacation!).  I would not have understood the mechanics of it without the assistance and breakdown, so I leaned quite a bit today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is *close*, but its output isn't quite what you need.  Let's look at that in closer detail.

### Breaking down your code

#### The `for-each`

This doesn't have any big impact on performance or output, but it seems out of place for your circumstances.

```
<xsl:for-each select="SpeedOfService">
```

There's only one `SpeedOfService` in your sample input XML.  You're also not doing anything fancy with this, just looping through the `ServiceTiming` children.  It would be more XSL-y, and cleaner code, to leave this out entirely and change your initial template opening line to this instead:

```
<xsl:template match="/SpeedOfService">
```

If your actual working input XML file has multiple `SpeedOfService` elements, I'd recommend using `<xsl:apply-templates/>` and then creating a separate `<xsl:template match="SpeedOfService">` template.

#### The first `for-each-group`

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="ServiceTiming" group-by="TransactionNumber">
    <xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
```

This does just what you need it to do, and as you described your needs -- it groups all `ServiceTiming` elements into groups by `TransactionNumber`, from largest to smallest.  This produces groups like:

```
<SAMPLE_GROUP>
    <ServiceTiming>
        <TransactionNumber>7773324</TransactionNumber>
        <VirtualDisplayId>101</VirtualDisplayId>
        <TableName>JUSTIN K2084</TableName>
    </ServiceTiming>
    <ServiceTiming>
        <TransactionNumber>7773324</TransactionNumber>
        <VirtualDisplayId>501</VirtualDisplayId>
        <TableName>JUSTIN K2084</TableName>
    </ServiceTiming>
    <ServiceTiming>
        <TransactionNumber>7773324</TransactionNumber>
        <VirtualDisplayId>401</VirtualDisplayId>
        <TableName>JUSTIN K2084</TableName>
    </ServiceTiming>
    <ServiceTiming>
        <TransactionNumber>7773324</TransactionNumber>
        <VirtualDisplayId>301</VirtualDisplayId>
        <TableName>JUSTIN K2084</TableName>
    </ServiceTiming>
    <ServiceTiming>
        <TransactionNumber>7773324</TransactionNumber>
        <VirtualDisplayId>201</VirtualDisplayId>
        <TableName>JUSTIN K2084</TableName>
    </ServiceTiming>
</SAMPLE_GROUP>
```

It's the next bit where things go slightly off the rails.

#### The second `for-each-group`

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="VirtualDisplayId">
```

This takes the `current-group()` and groups this set of elements by `VirtualDisplayId`.

This actually does just what it should.  However, since the set of grouped `ServiceTiming` elements in your dataset already only contain unique `VirtualDisplayId` values (all the `JUSTIN K2084` ones have different `VirtualDisplayId`s, etc.), this `for-each-group` doesn't actually do anything useful.

Moreover, when grouping by `VirtualDisplayId`, it's only grouping **within** the groups we just made -- and these have no visibility into any of the other groups.  So the context for the `JUSTIN K2084` group does **not** include any of the context for the `ANDY K2084` group.  Consequently, we can't group within these groups in any way that will have an impact on the grouping within other groups -- which is why you're getting output with two different `TableName` values but with identical `VirtualDisplayId` values.

```
...
<tr>
    <td>JUSTIN K2084</td>
    <td>101</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>ANDY K2084</td>
    <td>101</td>
</tr>
...
```

#### The `if`

This seems to be an attempt to limit output to just the first set of elements within this group.  Instead of this:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="VirtualDisplayId">
    <xsl:if test="position()=1">
```

... we could instead just `select` that same first set using `[1]`, and leave the `xsl:if` out entirely:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()[1]" group-by="VirtualDisplayId">
```

... but we've already established that grouping by `VirtualDisplayId` isn't doing anything anyway.  Ultimately, your code outputs the same set of eight table rows after omitting the second `for-each-group` and the `if`:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="ServiceTiming" group-by="TransactionNumber">
    <xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
    <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/TableName"/></td><td><xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/VirtualDisplayId"/></td></tr>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

#### The `select` statements

Within the context of `for-each-group`, selecting "this" `.` is the same thing as selecting `current-group()[1]`.  Per [the XSLT 2.0 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group) (emphasis mine):

> Within the sequence constructor, **the context item is the initial item of the relevant group**...

We can thus tighten up our code a bit:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="ServiceTiming" group-by="TransactionNumber">
    <xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
    <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="./TableName"/></td><td><xsl:value-of select="./VirtualDisplayId"/></td></tr>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Output:

```
  <tr>
     <td>JUSTIN K2084</td>
     <td>101</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>ANDY K2084</td>
     <td>101</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>ANDY K2083</td>
     <td>201</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>ANDY K2082</td>
     <td>301</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>ANDY K2081</td>
     <td>401</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>ANDY K2080</td>
     <td>501</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>ANDY K2079</td>
     <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>ANDY K2078</td>
     <td>200</td>
  </tr>
```

#### Limiting output to just the first five

We could limit output by adding in an `if` statement that checks for `position() < 6`:

```
<xsl:if test="position() &lt; 6">
    <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="./TableName"/></td><td><xsl:value-of select="./VirtualDisplayId"/></td></tr>
</xsl:if>
```

Although this does output only five table rows, the values are still not what we want -- we still have two rows with `VirtualDisplayId` values of `101`.

### An alternative approach

So how do we group first by `TransactionNumber`, and then a second time by `VirtualDisplayId`, but in a way where the second grouping is aware of the first one?

One way to do this is to store the results of the first grouping in a variable: the eight table rows we got further above.

```
<xsl:variable name="First_Group">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="ServiceTiming" group-by="TransactionNumber">
        <xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="./TableName"/></td><td><xsl:value-of select="./VirtualDisplayId"/></td></tr>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then we apply the second grouping to that variable.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="$First_Group/tr" group-by="td[2]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

We use `group-by="td[2]"` because the `VirtualDisplayId` values are in the second table cell of each row.

This gets us even closer to what we want: we now have a set of table rows where every `VirtualDisplayId` only appears once.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>JUSTIN K2084</td>
        <td>101</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ANDY K2083</td>
        <td>201</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ANDY K2082</td>
        <td>301</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ANDY K2081</td>
        <td>401</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ANDY K2080</td>
        <td>501</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ANDY K2079</td>
        <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ANDY K2078</td>
        <td>200</td>
    </tr>
</table
```

To limit the table output to just the first five rows, we now add in that `if` statement to check the position:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="$First_Group/tr" group-by="td[2]">
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt; 6">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

And we get our desired output:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>JUSTIN K2084</td>
        <td>101</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ANDY K2083</td>
        <td>201</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ANDY K2082</td>
        <td>301</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ANDY K2081</td>
        <td>401</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ANDY K2080</td>
        <td>501</td>
    </tr>
</table
```

#### The entire working stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/SpeedOfService">
        <table>
            <xsl:variable name="First_Group">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="ServiceTiming" group-by="TransactionNumber">
                    <xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                    <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="./TableName"/></td><td><xsl:value-of select="./VirtualDisplayId"/></td></tr>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="$First_Group/tr" group-by="td[2]">
                <xsl:if test="position() &lt; 6">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
<xsl:template match="/table">
  <xsl:variable name="table" select="." />
  <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(tr/td[2])">
    <xsl:variable name="group" select="."/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$table/tr[td[2][text()=$group]][1]"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltransform.net/6pS1zCZ